# WP custom post types pagination/404 error

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm using a custom post type in WordPress (called "ns_news_article" generated from Magic Fields) which are registered and working. This rewrites the URL to add "category/news" after the domain (so: www.mydomain.com/category/news/custom-post-1). I have to have the "fake directories" in there.

I have this in the functions.php:

```
add_rewrite_rule("[ns_news_article]" . '$', "index.php?pagename=[ns_news_article]", "top");
add_rewrite_rule("[ns_news_article]" . '/page/([0-9])*/?', "index.php?pagename=[ns_news_article]" . '&paged=$matches[1]', "top"); 
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

The 2nd line takes care of pagination 404 problem when viewing as multiple pages of lists, but then gives 404 errors when trying to view the single post. If I get rid of this, you can view the posts, but pagination doesn't work.

Can I fix this or should it be done another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently done custom post types pagination, so this is how I've done. Let's say your custom post type it's called "customp".

1. Create a file in your theme called `page-customp.php`. Then publish an empty page with "Customp" title. Now, when you're visiting www.yourdomain.com/customp you will see a page that is using `page-customp.php` as a template. Now we will be using this page to show the custom posts and with a pagination.
2. Place this code in `your page-customp.php` file:

   ```
   $paged = 1;

   $postsPerPage = 5;

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');

    if ( get_query_var('page') )  $paged = get_query_var('page');

    query_posts( '&post_type=customp&paged=' . $paged . '&posts_per_page='.$postsPerPage );

   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

     the_title();
     echo get_the_excerpt();

   endwhile;

   customp_paginate();
   ```
3. In your `functions.php` file place this:

   ```
   function customp_paginate() {

     global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;

     $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

     $pagination = array(
       'base' => @add_query_arg('page', '%#%'),
       'format' => '',
       'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
       'current' => $current,
       'show_all' => true,
       'type' => 'list',
       'prev_text' => '&laquo;',
       'next_text' => '&raquo;',
     );

     if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks())
       $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(remove_query_arg('s', get_pagenum_link(1))) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

     if (!empty($wp_query) && $pagination['total'] != 1) {
       $pagination['add_args'] = array('s' => get_query_var('s'));

       echo "<div class='paginate'><strong>Pages:</strong>" . paginate_links($pagination) . "</div>";
     }

   }
   ```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: You need to indent it with 8 spaces (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3793/245388)